# Fill Fact_Table from other tables SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I'm new on SSIS and I need your help. I have the following tables:

```
Fact_Table(date_debut_alarm,date_fin_alarm,,BTS,id_temp_deb,id_temp_fin,numOfweek,T,a,pond,t_pond)

dim_BTS(BTS,BSC,statut,date_BTS,class,Id_Ville)

dim_Calendar_deb(id-temp_deb,date_deb,year,month,trimestre,week)

dim_Calendar_fin(id-temp_fin,date_fin,year,month,trimestre,week)
```

And a staging table:

```
[alarmstg]([Alarm Description] ,date_deb_alarm ,date_fin_alarm,[Server] ,[BSC] ,[BTS_ID] ,[BSC_BTS] ,[BTS] )
```

I want to fill `fact_table` by using these tables. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could benefit from some training in SSIS fundamentals.

[Plurlsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/ssis-basic) videos are pretty good. If you have a training budget, I would look for SSIS training put on by Pragmatic Works.

Without knowing anymore specifics, I would create a seperate `Data Flow` for each table you need to load.

Good luck.

Comment: yes it's look a good website t trining but i don't have a budget i'm student , i need just to help me how to create a merge sql statement to add data on Fact_Table  thank you

Comment: If you can do what you need to do in a `MERGE` statement, you likely don't need SSIS. Try working out the kinks in your SQL with SSMS, and then put it into a stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you very much ,i used SSIS to fill Fact_Table but i didn't succeed to fill not all attributes i want to fill table_fact attributes id-temp-start,id-temp-end,weekNum by using the both date tables by comparing table_fact.date_start with dim_date_start.date and get id-date-start and put it on id-temp-start and table_fact.date_end with dim_date_end.date and get id-date-end and put it on id-temp-end Thank you very much

Comment: What you can try is dumping the data you have for the _Fact_ table in a `RAW` file. `RAW` files are good for staging data. Then one at a time, update the `RAW` file with your missing attributes. Once all the data is present, the `RAW` file can then be used to load the _Fact_ table. [See this blog post for more information](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-raw-files-are-awesome-131/)

Comment: thank you very much , but i have already fill data from Excel file to staging table , i need just to compare date_debut_alarm and date_fin-alarm with date in dim_calendar_date to get Id_temp-deb and id-temp-fin  and put it on Fact_Table thank you

Comment: If I understand what you need to do, I suggest the Lookup Transformation. [SSIS- Lookup Transform](http://www.dwbiconcepts.com/etl/29-etl-ssis/144-ssis-lookup-transform.html)

Comment: i tried but doesn't work how can i do it with sql statement  on execute sql  task

Answer (score 0):

Merge fact_table as target using( select idDateStart,weekofEmployees from dbo.dim_date_deb)as source on source.date_debut_alarm=target.date_deb when matched then update set target.idDate_tem_deb=source.id_temp_deb;